# Truncation of a string in MySQL during insertion and when string contains special character 'á'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, special-characters

Why do a string truncate when a try to insert in a MySQL table? The string truncates before the character `á`. For instance, `Málaga - Real Madrid` becomes only a `M`in the database.

```
//***
login & select database
//***
$mysqli->query('set names utf8');
$title = $mysqli->real_escape_string('Málaga - Real Madrid');
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO article (title) VALUES ('$title')");
```

Comment: Are you sure that that `á` is a utf-8 `á`?

Comment: And are you sure the charset of the title field is UTF-8 as well?

Comment: No I'm not sure. I'm fetching the data from an another website. I think though it is not UTF-8. Can I somehow convert it to UTF-8?

Comment: ok found the php function mb_convert_encoding for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to split a string at your character á

```
<?php
// Put the data in to a string
$string = 'Málaga - Real Madrid';

// Split it by the character
$split_string = explode('á', $string);

//***
login & select database
***/
$mysqli->query('set names utf8');

// Put the first split in to the real_escape function
$title = $mysqli->real_escape_string($split_string[0]);

// Run the query
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO article (title) VALUES ('$title')");

?>
```